# Toggle checkbox in a group via code

Tags: unity-game-engine

So far I know that I can cache the checkbox GO, and then use the isOn method to change it from on to off.

Is there another way, that would allow me to switch state on these checkbox, without the need to cache the objects itself? They belong in a group, so ther eis always only one checkbox enabled, and the others are off.

Ideally, since there are only 2 checkbox, it is either in one state or another, so either checkbox change in value would work.

I did try to change the value, getting the component from the pane on which the checkbox are, but changing the value won't have any effect.

I did check if the group had some sort of automation to switch the values but it simply return you if there is a value checked (not useful in my case, since I know that one value must be on by default).

Comment: is this the new UI? Just making sure, even though the isOn field is Unity.UI member. Not on GUI. Got a bit confused. about the cache object reference. So summing things up, you just want to create 2 checkbox that initially turned off without using isOn field?

Comment: Yes, new UI. I have already the 2 checkbox; and they are in a group. Now I have the reference to each of them, and I change the isOn=true when needed. Instead I was looking for a way to not create the reference to both controls, and use the fact that they are under a group.

Comment: Under a group. You're trying to achieve to 1 is always enabled only?

Comment: @newbiez Even though your code may not be working, you still need to provide it.

Comment: @Aizen; I was able to do that via editor: once you put both in a group, activating one will result in deactivation of the other. Although doing the same via code, with the isOn does not do the same thing....basically nothing change when I call isON and set it to a different value.

Comment: @Programmer: My code works fine; which is why I didn't post it. I am learning if there is a different way to swap values for these 2 checkbox, without having to cache the 2 checkbox and access them individually.

Comment: I just tested that and I see what you are saying. I don't think there is a way to do this because ToggleGroup requires that you change each a Toggle that is FALSE to TRUE before the rest of the toggle changes. If the current toggle is  TRUE and you set it to FALSE, it wont do anything. Although I have a method to get the current Toggle that is on but that is not useful because you need both toggles to actually change the toggle. Can you explain why you want to do this which out caching both of them.Maybe there is a better solution....

Comment: Thanks for your insight; I did bang my head on the wall to find a better way, but I assume this is the best that is possible to obtain with such UI system. I can only imagine the pain of having multiple checkbox in a group, and have to switch them after cache each of them....in my case is just 2 elements so no big deal, but I can see cases with 6-8 or more in a single group, and that means overcomplicating the code.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Using array should solve that problem.